# how can Export the class and define middleware in typescript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, express, routing-controllers

I create the class user where i just only define the get method but when i call the class in middleware and use it, it not show any error but when i run the code it show server not found. when i del this line **app.use(userRoute)** my server work.

users.ts

```
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from 'express';
import { Controller, Get, Req, Res } from 'routing-controllers'

@Controller()
class User {
    @Get('/signup')

    signUP(@Req() req: Request, @Res() res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
        return res.render('signup')

    };
}

export { User as userRoute }
```

app.ts

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const app = express()
import { userRoute } from "./routes/user";

const bodyPaser = require('body-parser')


app.use(bodyPaser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')


app.use(userRoute)

app.use('/', (req, res) => {

    res.write('<html lang="eng">');
    res.write('<head><title>Page</title><style>body{background-color: wheat; color: red; font-      size: 25px; padding-left: 250px;}.d{}</style></head>')
    res.write('<body><h1>It is working</h1></body>')
    res.write('</html>')
    return res.end()
});

app.listen('3000')
console.log('working')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create instance of your class before export.
Try some like:

```
class User {
...
}

const userRoute =  new User()
export {userRoute}
```

> **Updated based in doc of `routing-controllers`**

according to the [github](https://github.com/typestack/routing-controllers) page of that library, the use in express should be like this:

```
@Controller()
export class UserController {

    @Get("/users")
    getAll(@Req() request: Request, @Res() response: Response) {
        return response.send("Hello response!");
    }

}


import "reflect-metadata";
import { useExpressServer } from "routing-controllers";

let express = require("express"); // or you can import it if you have installed typings
let app = express(); // your created express server
// app.use() // you can configure it the way you want
useExpressServer(app, { // register created express server in routing-controllers
    controllers: [UserController] // and configure it the way you need (controllers, validation, etc.)
});
app.listen(3000); // run your express server
```

take a look at their doc

Comment: i tried this method also it show error: TypeError: app.use() requires a middleware function

Comment: I updated the response in the way that the library's documentation recommends using.